# While Loop in Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am trying to write a program that will loop when the user inputs a "y" or "yes" it.

```
System.out.println("Tuition Wasted Based on Studnet Absences and its effacton GPA");

System.out.println("Enter the number of students to consider: ");

students = keyboard.nextInt(); 

while (choice == y)
{

if (students >= 1 && students <= 5)

{
for(int i = 0; i < students; i++)
{
    System.out.print("\nEnter the student ID for student: ");
    studentID = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Do you want to run the program again?");

    choice = keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

Please help every time I type in y or yes I keep getting errors

Comment: Not enough info to help: what is `choice`? What is `y`? - looks like `choice` is an int but you expect it to be a char?

Comment: Also a studentID being a double is weird

Comment: Give us the errors please.  And probably more of the code would be nice.

Comment: Does you project really compile?  The snippet you gave, even if we assumed that you filled in the missing variables, has a lot of issues.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot wrong here...

1. What's y?  You've written the code as if there is a *variable* y.  The y on the `while (choice == y)` line need to be in single, or perhaps double, quotes, depending on the type of `choice`.
2. What's `choice` on your first pass through the while loop?  Where is it declared?  What it its type?
3. What's the return type of `nextInt()`?  Hint: int :-)  That will influence whether or not you wrap that y in single or double quotes.  Look into char vs. String in Java, and how they are compared...

Answer (score 1):

In using a `while` loop you should declare first the initial value of it on the declarations.

Example:

`String choice ="y"`

`//and so on...`

`while (choice.equals("y")) {`

`//your stuffs here`

`}`

PS

What's the data type of your `"y"`? I assumed you declared it as `Integer` cus you used a `"=="` sign you cant use `"double-equals"` sign on a `String`. You should change it to `String` and make a use of `".equals"` instead.

Try to consider using `do-while` loop

Ex:

`//your declarations..and so on`

`String choice;`

`System.out.println("Tuition Wasted Based on Studnet Absences and its effacton GPA");`

`System.out.println("Enter the number of students to consider: ");`

`students = keyboard.nextInt();`

`do {`

`if (students >= 1 && students <= 5)`

`{`
`for(int i = 0; i < students; i++)
{`

```
System.out.print("\nEnter the student ID for student: ");
studentID = keyboard.nextDouble();`

System.out.println("Do you want to run the program again?");`

choice = keyboard.next();
```

`}while (choice.equals("y") || choice.equals("yes"));`

Comment: Something like @Nameka said.